# Easy Confusion on Convex Optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I just a quick question regarding Convex Optimization. Say I am solving the Multiple Variable problem. And it satisfies the following conditions, except for the last one highlighted ($f(x)$ is **non-convex**). I am wondering, if I solve the Lagrangian, and compares each critical points, am I guaranteed to find the optimum point on the Constrained optimization problem?

Do I also need the function and the domain to be convex???

[image]

Comment: The condition between "Solve" and "to get the candidates" is called [KKT condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). It is known to be sufficient if (in these notations) $g$ are affine (equalities) and $h$ are convex (inequalities). The highlighted text mixes up $g$ and $h$ (wrong!).

Comment: So if $f(x)$ is **non-convex**, can I simply solve the equations between SOLVE, and TO GET CANDIDATES. Are the optimal point guaranteed to be one of these candidates points $x^*$ ?

Comment: In general, you need also to ensure that the solution exists (it is the standard prerequisite for using necessary conditions) plus to find all points of irregularities (where some kind of [constraint qualification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)) is not satisfied). Then the minimum is among KKT solutions or points of irregularities.

Comment: Under at least one CQ , constraint qualification , yes the solution of KKT system gives you the candidates of optimality.

Comment: What is CQ @Redshoes

Comment: I mentioned it.  constraint qualification

Answer (score 1):

Karush–Kuhn–Tucker ([KKT](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf#page=7)) conditions are four necessary conditions for any local optimal point. Therefore, if any optimal solution exists, it must satisfy all of those conditions. These conditions do not relay on any convexity.

Therefore, one can conclude that, for any nonlinear programming problem either convex or none-convex in the function or domain, the optimum solution candidates (if exist) are satisfying KKT. So, feel free to use KKT to obtain the optimal solution candidates.

Comment: are you sure? So the most optimal point (if exists) should be the canadidates from KKT?

Comment: @kou, Yes, Many solvers rely on these conditions to solve such as qpOASES see Theorem 2.5 at page [19](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.8250&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=37) and see equation 3.1.2 at page [27](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.8250&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=45) . This equation is what is often solved to obtain the solution. I recommend reading this thesis if you are interested in this area.